# How to Store Dir and findStr result in variable in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am working on creating a batch file which will perform some operations I am having trouble saving the result of the command into a variable. The command is below,

```
dir /b /s *.bin | findstr /i "non_RSA_"
```

this gives me one file from a directory I need to save the path of the file into a variable so I can use elsewhere in the batch file.

Comment: `for /r %%I in (*non_RSA_*.bin) do set "var=%%I"` (gives the (last) found file). `... do set "var=%%~dpI"` gives the path of that file.

Comment: @Stephan thanks for the help. You gave me the answer without criticizing my question. thanks